# Ask about verb tense in "now it gets flickering screen"

Tags: tense, verbs

I have this sentence:

> I accidentally splashed water on my phone, now it gets flickering screen, can i fix it by putting it into rice container

In the first clause, splash ~> splashed (simple past).
Now i'm confusing about what tense of "get" should be?

Comment: It is, and should be, present tense, as you are describing a symptom it has *now*.  You are **confused about**, not *confusing about*.

Comment: By the way, you have two comma splices in your quote. Sentences are delimited by a full stop ".", not a comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about **now**, it's best not to use the word **get**

Get refers to a **change** in state- maybe that happened in the past.

> I left my phone outside and it **got** wet.

If you want to talk about now, you should talk about the current state:

> I left my phone outside and now it **is** wet.
>   I left my phone outside and now the screen **is** flickering
>   I left my phone outside and now it **has** a flickering screen.

Looking at your sentence:

> I accidentally splashed water on my phone, *and* now it **has** *a* flickering screen. Can I fix it by putting it into *a* rice container?

Answer (score 5):

The correct tense for *to get* in your sentence is the present tense, which you have used.

However, your sentence is not the sentence a native speaker would use. *To get* is not often used to describe the current state of something:

> It **will get** warm on Monday.
>
> He **has got** a stomach ache.

The more natural way for a native speaker to express this would either be using *to have* or *to flicker*. You would also want to use *and* after your comma:

> I accidentally splashed water on my phone, and now it **has** a 
>   flickering screen.
>
> I accidentally splashed water on my phone, and now **its screen flickers**.

Comment: present continuous **is flickering** might be better in your last sentence.

Comment: @JavaLatte: To me, *now its screen flickers* implies that the flickering is something that is (semi-)permanent, whereas *is flickering* only means that the flickering is happening now, and may go away in future: "The TV is flickering because the aerial is bent." vs. "We bent the aerial and now the TV flickers."

Comment: The problem is not with **gets** but with "flickering screen" with **gets**. A native speaker could say "The screen gets all flickery" (to mean that it [soon or eventually] becomes very flickery) or as you say, "the screen flickers" or "it has a flickering screen".